# Finding a letter from a list in a string. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write something that shows whether or not a letter in a list is in a string and for some reason what I've written always returns false. Where am I going wrong?

```
def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    for char in secret_word:
        if char not in letters_guessed:
            guess = False
            break
        else:
            guess = True
    return guess

print(is_word_guessed("python", ["o"]))
```

Comment: Your loop starts with the first letter of `secret_word`, which is "p", so it sets `guess` to false, and then breaks out of the loop. So the function returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are checking whether a letter isn't in the string so let's say you have the following data:

```
letters = ["p", "g", "a"]
word    = "python"
```

with this data the code will return `False` since the last letter you are checking, `"n"`, isn't in the list of letters.

Same goes for the data you gave:

```
letters = ["o"]
word    = "python"
```

since the first letter checked, `"p"`, isn't in the list then the code returns `False` since the loop breaks.

So basically, unless all the letters in the word are in the list of letters your code will simply just return `False`.

This is the code you should be using:

```
def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    for char in secret_word:
        if char in letters_guessed:
            return True
        return False

print(is_word_guessed("python", ["o"]))
```

The difference here is that instead of checking whether a character is NOT in the list it will check whether it is so instead of having to have a list with all the characters the list can have any character that is in the word. The reason we use `return True` directly in the loop in the if statement is because the `return` statement stops the execution of the function so if there aren't any matching characters then the function won't execute the `return True` so the function won't stop there and will go execute `return False` which will only execute if none of the characters are in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to test it the other way around and break out if you find the first matching character.

```
def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    for ch in secret_word:
        if ch in letters_guessed:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. because you are breaking from the loop you exited your function early.

```
def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    guess = None.  #Note you have to declare the variable guess before assigning below, since you are returning the guess in your function
    for char in secret_word:
        if char not in letters_guessed:
            guess = False
           
        else:
            guess = True
    return guess
```

#Option2:
I do not think you need to loop through since your string is an iterable. you can just check for their value and return the result

```
def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
      if char not in letters_guessed:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```